# How to quickly create complex web controls for web development?

Tags: jquery, css, spring, jakarta-ee

I know J2EE,Spring,jquery,JS,CSS. Whenever we build any web application then most of the time it require complex HTML controls to be built . Plugin which are freely available in jquery is good but most of the time it require lots of customization which takes lots of time and hence delay the project deliverable.

Is there any way were complex controls of web application can be built quickly? How to quickly develop web application ? Is there any tool or opensource project which can generate the code and make the development process faster?

Mostly till now I have developed project using 100% hand coding?So do Normally everyone develop java/j2ee webapplication using handcoding or is there any automated tool ?

Comment: How would the automated tool know what html you want to generate?

Comment: PS, you should be grateful that there aren't any magic code generators that are widely in use. Otherwise, you're value as a web developer would drop significantly!

Comment: @lbstr ur right..but any drag and drop tool which can let me do customization easily and modify the behaviour of the control to some extent..? Or let me design page quickly atleast with cool controls..?Do you develop code using hand written code?

Comment: Yes, I do develop with just hand written code. I think what your talking about is something like [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html). This allows you to drag things around the page and the code is automatically generated/adjusted for you. I'm not familiar with the j2ee world, so I don't know if there are any similar editors out there for that type of environment.

Comment: I typically automate all my web development by paying a bunch of developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JavaScript MVC framework makes it easy to manage complex controls.

Flixster / Rotten Tomatoes is a Spring shop and used JavaScript, Backbone.js and jQuery UI to create this site with complex UI controls (all handwritten):  http://www.rottentomatoes.com/dvd/netflix/?debug=true

Conceptually, this is how they used Backbone.js:

- The searchquery model contains all the search parameters and the results
- Multiple views (tomatometer range, release date) are bound to that same model and update it when a user toggles checkboxes or moves the slider back and forth.

You don't have to use Backbone, there are other JavaScript frameworks out there as well like Ember.js and Angularjs.  I would just highly recommend using a framework -- they help you develop fast when you're dealing with any complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't build the HTML for the controls. The HTML should convey the meaning of the content you're delivering, that's its point.

Plugins are meant to be tinkered with. We can't always use

```
<div id="specific_name">
    <img rel="slider" href="whatever">
    <span rel="caption">Hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: appologize..I wanted to mean web control..I want to come out hancoding to develop complex web controls..Do experts hancode to develop applications?